# Returning specific elements with Dataset api

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

i wrote a tfrecord file in which i have images and their labels.Then i can pick them up using

```
    def parserTrain(record):
        keys_to_features = {
            "image_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
            "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64,
                                        default_value=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int64)),
        }
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

        # Perform additional preprocessing on the parsed data.
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(parsed["image_raw"])
        image = tf.reshape(image, [256, 256, 3])

        image = tf.transpose(image, perm=[2, 0, 1])  # channels first
        image = tf.truediv(image, 255.0)
        label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.int32)

        return {"image": image}, label

    # Set up training input function.
    def train_input_fn():
        """Prepare data for training."""
        train_tfrecord = 'Dataset/train_images.tfrecords'

        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_tfrecord)
        dataset = dataset.map(parserTrain)
```

after that i want to filter out some examples using probably something like this:

```
def f(x):
    return x[1] == 1


ds1 = dataset.filter(f)
```

but i get this error:

> TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to my question as i found the answer.
the correct syntax for a filter function to a dataset of tuples is the following:

```
def f(im, label):
    return tf.equal(label, 1)


ds1 = dataset.filter(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, given you have a dataset (e.g. a `TFRecordDataset`) you can filter the examples as follows:

```py
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=files)
  dataset = dataset.filter(lambda example: example["value"] == value and example["label"] == label)
  dataset = ...
```

Comment: I think I don't understand the question completely. So you want a generator, that returns a batch, where each sample has the same label. But different labels for every batch?

Comment: yes thats what i need. The only way i can think of doing this if i create a for loop and then to create dataset based on a specific label but i dont know how efficient this is

Comment: @christk Please add further details to your question directly.

Comment: @lhlmgr i completely changed the question and it is straight to the point, you can take a look :)